# my jquery plugin wont accept my options! help!

Tags: jquery, plugins

okay i making a jQuery plugin to make a slide down menu on click, everything works on it but when i try to pass my own options it ignores them help please?

http://jsfiddle.net/y5kC6/2/
theres is a jsfiddle so you can get a better thought of what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have any named parameters.

change

```
$.fn.plugin = function()
```

to

```
$.fn.plugin = function(options)
```

Comment: oh that's it?! i was just looking on jquery.com and i noticed that.

Comment: you will also have to eliminate the `var`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set up your function to receive passed parameters.

Change it to something like this...

```
$.fn.plugin = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        speed: 500,
        margin: '-40px',
    };

    if(options) {
        $.extend(defaults,options);
    }
```

Comment: I also recommend changing the object name from "defaults" to "settings", then, in your plugin script, you would access your values with `settings.parameterName`.

Comment: im guessing the if(options) {} is so that if $.fn.plugin = function(options) {}; exists if makes the $.extend?

Comment: Yeah, the conditional is there in case the plugin is called without being passed any parameters.